# Evaluate the$\int_0^1\int_{\sin^{-1} y}^{\pi/2} \cos x\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}\,dxdy$ and $\int_0^2\int_0^1\int_y^1 \sinh(z^2)\,dzdydx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> 1. Evaluate the following integrals:
>      \begin{gather}
>    \int_0^1\int_{\sin^{-1} y}^{\pi/2} \cos x\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}\,dxdy;\\
>    \int_0^2\int_0^1\int_y^1 \sinh(z^2)\,dzdydx
>    \end{gather}

1. I tried doing integration by parts, got nowhere as nothing seems to reduce. I tried converting $\cos(x)^2$ into $1-\sin(x)^2$ and u-sub, but ended up with $\sqrt{2-u^2}$. Again stuck.
2. Know the hyperbolic equivalents $\sinh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$, and evaluate the integral with $x=z^2$.

Help with number 1? Also maybe links to how to deal with these types of integrals?

Comment: Please don't post images, especially low quality ones. Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead and type images out.

Comment: Got it. Wondered what everyone was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Help with number 1?*

**Hint**. You are on the right track. To evaluate 
$$
\int \sqrt{2-u^2}du
$$ one may use the change of variable $u=\sqrt{2}\cdot \sin t$ obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{2-u^2}du&=2\int \cos^2 t \:dt
\\&=2\int \left(\frac12+\frac{\cos (2t)}2 \right)dt
\\&=\int \left(1+\cos (2t) \right)dt
\\&=t+\frac{\sin (2t)}2
\\&=t+\sin t \cdot \cos t
\\&=\arcsin\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{2}u \sqrt{2-u^2}.
\end{align}
$$ Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\arcsin y}^{\pi/2}\cos x \cdot \sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}\:dx&=\int_{\arcsin y}^{\pi/2}\cos x \cdot \sqrt{2-\sin^2 x}\:dx
\\\\&=\int_{y}^{1}\sqrt{2-u^2 }\:du
\\\\&=\frac12+\frac{\pi}4-\frac12\cdot y \sqrt{2-y^2}-\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{align}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Easier than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

The trick for integral number 2 is to switch the order of integration as integrating with respect to y is much easier than with respect to z.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} sinh(z^2) dz dy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{z} sinh(z^2) dy dz$$

Now evaluating the inner integral is no problem and the result is

$$\int_{0}^{1} z sinh(z^2) dz$$

Now substitute $u = z^2$ to finish off the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first integral there is also another quicker solution strategy applying differently the Fubini's theorem. Indeed, the domain of integration can also be expressed as the region of the plane given by
$$
\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;:\; y\in[0,\sin x]\;\forall x\in[0,2\pi]\}.
$$
Then, we have
\begin{align}
     \int^{1}_{0}\int^{\pi/2}_{\arcsin y} \cos x \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}\, dx\, dy
     & =\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\int^{\sin x}_{0} \cos x \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}\, dx\,dy 
     \\
&
=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\bigg(\int^{\sin x}_{0}\,dy \bigg)\cos x \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}\, dx 
\\
&
=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\underbrace{\sin x\cos x \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}}_{=\,\frac{d}{dx}\big(-\frac{1}{3}(1+\cos^2x)^{3/2}\big)}\; dx
\\
&
 =\Big[-\frac{1}{3}(1+\cos^2x)^{3/2}\Big]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0
\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\Big(2^{\frac{3}{2}}-1\Big).
&
\end{align}